# Fraction class returns strings instead of solved fraction

Tags: java

I got this code for Java Fraction class to use and determine the output and file a document as an assignment. But when I use this class to solve an actual fraction, it doesn't give me the actual result but only random strings.

The output:

```
C:\Users\Jack\Documents\assign>java testFrac
Fraction@3485097d + Fraction@a32087b - Fraction@5acac877 = Fraction@372f2b32
```

Fraction.java

```
public class Fraction {
  private int num;    // numerator 
  private int denom;  // denominator 
  public Fraction(int n, int d) {
    int g; 
    if (d == 0) { 
          System.out.println("Fraction: fraction "
      + "with 0 denominator?"); System.exit(1); 
    } 
    if (n == 0) {
      num = 0; 
      denom = 1; 
        } else {
      if (d < 0) {
        n = -n; 
        d = -d; 
      }
      if ((g = gcd(n, d)) != 1) { // remove gcd
        n /= g;
        d /= g;
      }
      num = n; 
      denom = d; 
    }
  } 
  private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    a = Math.abs(a); 
    b = Math.abs(b); 
    if (a == 0) return b; // 0 is error value 
    if (b == 0) return a; 
    int t; 
    while (b > 0) {
      t = a % b; // take "-" to the extreme 
      a = b; 
      b = t; 
    }
    return a; 
  }
  public boolean isZero() {
    return (denom == 1 && num == 0); 
  } 
  public boolean isInt() {
    return (denom == 1); 
  }
 public boolean equals(Fraction y) {
    return (num == y.num && denom == y.denom); 
  }
  public boolean greaterThan(Fraction y) {
    return (num * y.denom > denom * y.num); 
  }
  public Fraction minus(Fraction y) {
    return new Fraction(
      num * y.denom - y.num * denom, 
      denom * y.denom
    ); 
  }  
  public Fraction plus(Fraction y) {
    return new Fraction(
      num * y.denom + y.num * denom, 
      denom * y.denom
    ); 
  }  
  public Fraction times(Fraction y) {
    return new Fraction(num * y.num, denom * y.denom); 
  }  
  public Fraction dividedBy(Fraction y) {
    return new Fraction(num * y.denom, denom * y.num); 
  }  
}
```

testFrac.java

```
class testFrac {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fraction x = new Fraction( 1, 20); 
    Fraction u = new Fraction(1, 60); 
    Fraction v = new Fraction( 1, 30); 
    Fraction y; 
    y = x.plus(u).minus(v); // in one step!
    System.out.println( x + " + " + 
                        u + " - " + 
                        v + " = " + y); 
 }
}
```

Please guide me where I am getting this wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't override `toString()`, by default, when you print an object, you will simply see object's hashcode values (like your `Fraction@3485097d`, etc...).

So you need to override `toString()` method (from `java.lang.Object`) as shown below so that when you are using object of Fraction class it will print the string (like given below).

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Fraction [num=" + num + ", denom=" + denom + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please override `toString` method with something like

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return num + "/" + denom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `toString` method for your `Fraction` class; the default one is producing the "random" output you see (which isn't random at all).

Answer (score 0):

When you print a Fraction object,the `toString()` method is called.You need to override the [toString()](http://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method) method with something like

```
public String toString(){  
  return num+"/"+denom;  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are a live saver <3

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the Fraction object itself. To print this you need a String representation of the Fraction. You can override the `toString` method and do following

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        return num + "/" + denom;
}
```

and While printing call the `toString` method like following

```
System.out.println( x.toString() + " + " + 
                        u.toString() + " - " + 
                        v.toString() + " = " + y.toString());
```